# What query approach I can take to get data from 2 master and 1 master details table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I have 3 tables People, Distribution, DistributionPeopleDetails as follows:

[image]

I want to retrieve when people got last help and when they are supposed to get the next help.

I tried to join three tables in a different way but nothing giving me expected result, I'm not too experienced with SQL, so probably I'm just thinking the basic joins while it may need some advanced trick like group by etc. Can someone guide me please?

I've tried this so far:

```
select top 1 P.Name, d.DistributionDate as 'Next Scheduled Help'

from Peoples p left join [dbo].[DistributionPeopleDetails] dp on p.Id = 
dp.PeopleId
left join [dbo].[Distributions] d on dp.DistributionId = d.Id
where d.DistributionDate > GetDate() order by d.Id



select top 1 P.Name, d.DistributionDate as 'LastScheduled Help'

from Peoples p left join [dbo].[DistributionPeopleDetails] dp on p.Id = 
dp.PeopleId
left join [dbo].[Distributions] d on dp.DistributionId = d.Id
where d.DistributionDate < GetDate() order by d.Id
```

I kind off getting my expected result but I could not fit this snippet of query into my SP where I'm reading all the properties for People by joining few other tables.

What I got/want to get:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the results that you expect. It would also help providing your data as tabular text rather than images, and giving names to your tables.

Comment: *"I tried to join three tables in a different way but nothing giving me expected result"* Show us that attempt, explain to us why it didn't work.

Comment: Updated the question with code I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for joins and conditional aggregation, like so?

```
select
    p.peopleId,
    p.name,
    max(case when d.distributionDate < getdate() then distributionDate end) lastDistibutionDate,
    min(case when d.distributionDate > getdate() then distributionDate end) nextDistibutionDate
from people p
left join distributionPeople dp on dp.peopleId = p.peopleId
left join distribution d on d.distributionId = dp.distributionId
group by p.peopleId, p.name
```

This gives you one record per row in `people`, where column `lastDistibutionDate` contains the latest past `distributionDate` and column `nextDistibutionDate` is the closest next `distributionDate`.

Comment: I gave it a quick go and it seems this is what I was looking for. I will spend some time to understand the query you shared and mark your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I used your query to return a collection which I joined again with Peoples table to get everything I needed. :)